# Laravel Orderby Calculated Value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this function which should return values by distance, closer to further away. However receiving this error in Laravel: Use of undefined constant lat - assumed 'lat'

Code as follows:

```
public static function getNearby($lat, $lng, $distance = 50, $limit = 50) {

    $radius = 6371.009; // Earths radius in KM

    // Latitude Boundaries
    $minLat = (float) $lat - rad2deg($distance / $radius);
    $maxLat = (float) $lat + rad2deg($distance / $radius);

    // Longitude Boundaries
    $minLng = (float) $lng - rad2deg($distance / $radius / cos(deg2rad((float) $lat)));
    $maxLng = (float) $lng + rad2deg($distance / $radius / cos(deg2rad((float) $lat)));

    // Query DB
    $nearby = (array) DB::table('users')
        ->where('lat', '>', $minLat)
        ->where('lat', '<', $maxLat)
        ->where('lng', '>', $minLng)
        ->where('lng', '<', $maxLng)
        ->orderBy(ABS(lat - (float) $lat) + ABS(lng - (float) $lng), 'ASC')
        ->take($limit)
        ->get(); 

    var_dump($nearby);

}
```

Any suggestions here? I envisage I may have to do a DB:raw but am unsure how to incorporate that (if I have to)... Appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: ->orderBy(DB::raw('ABS(lat - (float) $lat) + ABS(lng - (float) $lng) ASC'))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `**DB::raw()**` function of eloquent.

In your case, the following query should work:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('ABS(lat - '.(float)$lat.') + ABS(lng - '.(float)$lng.')'),'ASC' )
```

Some more DB::raw usage Example

```
User::select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))->first();
User::select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count'),'status')->first();
User::select(DB::raw(1))->first();
```

Comment: Ah okay, this is where I headed but didn't use '', minor correction for it to work is ASC has to be outside raw, I'll edit then tick correct :) - thanks so much!

Comment: You can also use the `->orderByRaw()` method to improve the readability of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Way too late to help (but for posterity): wouldn't you want to use the Pythagorean equation for the raw SQL?

```
->orderBy(
  DB::raw('SQRT( POWER(lat - ' . (float)$lat . ', 2) + POWER(lng - ' . (float)$lng . ', 2) )',
  'asc'
)
```

The actual distance you want to order by is the radius (hypotenuse), correct?

Comment: If you are using the distance for sorting only, then there is no need to take the square root. That will just slow the query down. Sorting without taking the square root has the same result with regards to sorting.